# set theory, fixed points of a funtion $\Phi : P(A) \rightarrow P(A)$:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

suppose that $\Phi :P(A) \rightarrow P(A)$ for some set $A$ 
 
and we define $\Phi$ by: $$\Phi (X) = A\backslash g[B\backslash f[X]] \\ \Phi ^ 0 (X) = X \\ \Phi ^{n+1} (X) = \Phi (\Phi ^ n(X))$$ 
while $B$ is some group and $f:A\rightarrow B, g:B\rightarrow A$ are injective. 
and we define$$D(X)= \bigcup \left\{ \Phi ^n (X) | n \in \mathbb N \right\} $$
and i need to prove that if $X _0 \subseteq \Phi (X_0)$ than $D(X_0)$ is fixed point $\Phi (D(X_0)) = D(X_0)$
now my real problem is with $f,g$,I dont realy under their role. 
i tried proving by contradiction but couldnt find any
Thank you!

Comment: Is there a typo in your definition of $\Phi^{n+1}(X)$? Otherwise $\Phi^n(X) = X$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: yes fixed it thank you

Comment: קבוצה = set, חבורה = group.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the proof by contradiction.
You can see that from the assumption $X_0\subseteq \Phi(X_0)$ that $\Phi^n(X_0)\subseteq \Phi^m(X_0)$ if $n\le m$.

Moreover, $\Phi$ preserves arbitrary union: that is, we have
$\Phi(\bigcup\mathcal{C}) = \bigcup \{\Phi(C)\mid C\in\mathcal{C}\}$. (You need the injectivity of $g$ to prove this fact. It does not hold for general $g$.) Combining these two facts, you can prove $D(X_0)\subseteq \Phi(D(X_0))$ and $\Phi(D(X_0)) \subseteq D(X_0)$.